# "because you told me”, “…told me to" or “…told me so"?

Tags: meaning, ellipsis

Could you tell me which one of the following sentences is the most correct and natural?

> I quit smoking because you **told** me.
>
> I quit smoking because you **told** me **to**
>
> I quit smoking because you **told** me **so**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *tell someone to* do something. *You told me so* means something different.

> I know smoking is bad for me because you told me so.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but are my first and second sentence both correct?

Comment: It would be more usual to add _to_.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's second option is best because when the meaning is clear, the infinitival marker "to" can stand alone to create an [elliptical construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase_ellipsis), which allows the speaker to avoid repeating the same phrase twice. For example,

> I know I should [eat healthy foods like fruit and vegetables, and exercise more], but I just don’t want **to**.

- I quit smoking because you told me **to** [stop/quit smoking].

The third option is a bit strange because the meaning is different:

- I quit smoking because you told me **so**.

This is usually reserved for when someone predicts something which you disagree with, for example, “[Kanye West will win the US presidential election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West_2020_presidential_campaign)”. If the prediction (or *warning*) comes true and Kanye West is elected the president of the USA, the prognosticator can announce–“I told you so!”

> ### [I told you so](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/i-told-you-so)
>
> used when you have warned someone about a possible danger that has now happened and they have ignored your warning (*Longman Dictionary*)

> - *If she failed, her mother would say, '[I told you so](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/i-told-you-so).'*

Answer (score 0):

“I quit smoking because you told me **[to do so](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/101328/1694)**”
would be correct.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well and [may be deleted](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3294/18673).